# Perl , How to read subfolder Output

Tags: perl

I am writing a script to read the content of multiple sub folder in a directory. 
And recently i need to read the content of folder inside multiple sub-folder. 
Want to ask how can i write the code to read those folder inside multiple sub-folder.

This is the new conditions
**Multiple Sub-folder -> Local folder -> fileAAA.csv**
how do i read this fileAAA in Local folder of Multiple Sub-folder?

Currently the code i am writing was in this condition and it works well.
**Multiple Sub-folder -> fileAAA.csv**
Able to read fileAAA from multiple Sub-folder

Below is the code i use to read
**Multiple Sub-folder -> fileAAA.csv**

```
my ( $par_dir, $sub_dir );
opendir( $par_dir, "$parent" );
while ( my $sub_folders = readdir($par_dir) ) {
    next if ( $sub_folders =~ /^..?$/ );    # skip . and ..
    my $path = $parent . '/' . $sub_folders;
    next unless ( -d $path );               # skip anything that isn't a directory

    opendir( $sub_dir, $path );
    while ( my $file = readdir($sub_dir) ) {
        next unless $file =~ /\.csv?$/i;
        my $full_path = $path . '/' . $file;
        print_file_names($full_path);
    }
    closedir($sub_dir);
    $flag = 0;
}
closedir($par_dir);

 ......
```

Comment: If you lay your program out properly and indent it then it will help you to code more comfortably and accurately, and it will help others to read it when you ask questions. As it stands it's very difficult to read

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated

You should look at [the `File::Find` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) which has everything already in place to do searches like this, and has taken account of all corner cases for you

I wrote that on my tablet and at the time I couldn't offer sample code to support it. I believe this will do what you're asking for, which is simply to find all CSV files at any level beneath a parent directory

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find qw/ find /;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $parent = '/Multiple Sub-folder';

find(sub {
    return unless -f and /\.csv$/i;
    print_file_names($File::Find::name);
}, $parent);

sub print_file_names {
    my ($fn) = @_;
    print $fn, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Borodin , Thanks for the example and explaination. It was great. ^ ^

Comment: This script will be finding all the file in $parent. 
If i want to ignore certain of  the file where should i put it? 
Like i want to ignore those file naming "File1_datalog.csv" , what should i write with the script above?

Answer (score 0):

Without using moudle try this

Instead of `opendir` can you try [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) for subdirectory search.

In below script i make a subroutine for continuous search.
When elsif condition is satisfied the path of the directory is will go to the `find` subroutine then it'll seach and so on.

```
my $v = "/Multiple Sub-folder"; 
find($v);
sub find{
    my ($s) = @_;
    foreach my $ma (glob "$s/*")
    {
        if(-f $ma)
        {
            if($ma =~m/.csv$/) # Here search for csv files.
            {
                print "$ma\n";
            }
        }
        elsif(-d $ma)
        {
            find("$ma")
        }

    }
}
```

But can you use `File::Find` module for search the files in the directory as the answer of `Borodin` Which is the best approach.